# C++/QML sequence data exchange

Tags: c++, qt, type-conversion, qml

Is it possible to expose `QList<T>` from C++ to QML, where T type is known by meta object system?

```
//C++:
class Data : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<QGeoCoordinate> path READ path WRITE setPath NOTIFY pathChanged)
```

An Data instance exposed as context property to QML, but at QML side path property is undefined. 
In docs written

> In particular, QML currently supports:
>
> ```
> QList<int>
> QList<qreal>
> QList<bool>
> QList<QString> and QStringList
> QList<QUrl>
> ```
>
> Other sequence types are not supported transparently, and instead an
>   instance of any other sequence type will be passed between QML and C++
>   as an opaque QVariantList.

But looks like that opaque conversion to QVariantList doesn't work. 
I'm using Qt 5.6 RC snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what exactly is supposed to happen with the conversion to `QVariantList`. I don't see how you'd be able to access the contents of the list anyway, as the contained type is not a `QObject`. I think that the documentation could be made clearer there.

You can use [`QQmlListProperty`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmllistproperty.html) instead, though. The [Extending QML using Qt C++](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gettingstartedqml.html#extending-qml-using-qt-c) has more information on its use. Here's `directory.cpp` from that example's source code:

```
/*
    Function to append data into list property
*/
void appendFiles(QQmlListProperty<File> *property, File *file)
{
    Q_UNUSED(property)
    Q_UNUSED(file)
    // Do nothing. can't add to a directory using this method
}

/*
    Function called to retrieve file in the list using an index
*/
File* fileAt(QQmlListProperty<File> *property, int index)
{
    return static_cast< QList<File *> *>(property->data)->at(index);
}

/*
    Returns the number of files in the list
*/
int filesSize(QQmlListProperty<File> *property)
{
    return static_cast< QList<File *> *>(property->data)->size();
}

/*
    Function called to empty the list property contents
*/
void clearFilesPtr(QQmlListProperty<File> *property)
{
    return static_cast< QList<File *> *>(property->data)->clear();
}

/*
    Returns the list of files as a QQmlListProperty.
*/
QQmlListProperty<File> Directory::files()
{
    refresh();
    return QQmlListProperty<File>(this, &m_fileList, &appendFiles, &filesSize, &fileAt, &clearFilesPtr);
}
```

You could also do something similar by exposing a [`QList` of `QObject`-derived types](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html#properties-with-object-list-types), but that has its own fallbacks.